# Query MariaDB for Installation folder?

Tags: mariadb, information-schema

I can see there is a lot of information in the **information_schema** database, is there a standard way to get the installation path from the database?

I can see there are **GLOBAL_VARIABLES** table has several entries that include the installation folder, what I'm after is a way to get the **bin** folder from the database?

I'm using MariaDB 10.5 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, in **information_schema** the table **GLOBAL_VARIABLES** contains an entry with **VARIABLE_NAME** of **BASEDIR** the **VARIABLE_VALUE** contains the installation folder.

Comment: Use `SELECT @@BASEDIR;` for cross-OS compatibility.